# Type parameters, constraints and covariance/contravariance

Tags: c#, covariance, variance

Let's say I have the following classes that have different implementations based on the object to be stored in:

```
public class ListOfPersistent<T> : 
    IList<T> where T : Persistent {... implementation ...}

public class ListOfNonPersistent<T> : 
     IList<T> {... implementation ...}
```

And I want to use one of another version on the above classes by doing something like this:

```
public class PersistentList<T> : IList<T> {
  protected PersistentList() {
    if (list != null) {
      return;
    }

    if (Extensions.IsPersistent<T>()) {
      list = new ListOfPersistent<T>();

    } else {
      list = new ListOfNonPersistent<T>();
    }
  }

  protected IList<T> list;
  ....
}
```

Of course the above does not compiles, because there is a type constrain on the first class and none on the second. Is there any way I can: Tell the compiler that it should not check the constrain on this specific case (`list = new ListOfPersistent<T>()`) because I KNOW it will be of that type, or do some covariance/contravariance magic so the code compiles without any issues?

Answer (score 1):

Covariance and contravariance won’t help you here because `IList<T>` is invariant.

Personally I would argue that you have a flaw in your class design. You shouldn’t want to instantiate a `ListOfPersistent<T>` and then place it in a variable whose type, `IList<T>`, is incompatible. Unfortunately I cannot suggest a good alternative because I have no idea how you are planning to use these classes or what your overall goal is; but I can make *a* suggestion with a disclaimer that it is *hacky* and should probably only be used if you really know what you are doing:

```
public static class ListUtils
{
    public static object CreateListOfPersistent(Type elementType)
    {
        if (!typeof(Persistent).IsAssignableFrom(elementType))
            throw new ArgumentException("elementType must derive from Persistent.", "elementType");
        var listType = typeof(ListOfPersistent<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    }
}

// ...

if (Extensions.IsPersistent<T>())
    list = (IList<T>) ListUtils.CreateListOfPersistent(typeof(T));
else
    list = new ListOfNonPersistent<T>();
```

Comment: The two classes do the same thing, but since the inner working is completely different and one of them depends on the type to be Persistent, that's why there are two classes. Of course I can put a lot of if... on one of the classes, but that will be hard to maintain and not very fast. Basically, the PersistentList is only a decorator, as it does not has any functionality, just use the underlining functionality of the IList, that again, depending if the type of T is Persistent or not, needs two different implementations.

Comment: @CheloXL: Like I said, it is difficult to give you any advice on how to implement things without knowing what you are actually trying to do. You are only telling me how you are trying to implement it. In general, when I am in a situation where I need separate behaviour for two different kinds of object, I create a class hierarchy with virtual (or abstract) methods and put the differing functionality in those, and not into a specialised container class — but I can’t say whether this is applicable in your particular scenario.

Comment: I'm doing an object persistence manager. The Persistent class is the base class for all persistent objects, but it is not necessary to inherit that class in order to make an object persistent. The difference is that a class that inherits Persistent will be stored as a link (reference) to the class, and a class that does not inherits Persistent will be stored as-is (so, if the object is Persistent you will have only one obj and several references, if the obj is not Persistent, you will have several copies of the same class). That's why the two implementations are different.

Comment: But I want to have one facade class where I can create "Lists" without having to worry if the resulting list will be of Persistent objects or not. I can remove the constrain on the first implementation and then cast all the results. That will work, but again, I don't see that as a good solution.

Comment: @CheloXL: From your description I don’t see the need for a specialised list. All the functionality you described should be in the `Persistent` abstract class (or alternatively, in an interface that it implements). Even if you *could* have the list the way you described, I don’t see how you could get around doing any casting; you’d still need to cast all the (unconstrained) `T`'s to `Persistent` before you could use any functionality that is specific to `Persistent`.